# all my edit button cannot work and got "Invalid form POST data" AJAX error

Tags: 7, ajax, debugging

I don't know why all my edit button doesn't work since yesterday. In the log report, I got an AJAX HTTP error with 200 HTTP Code and "**Invalid form POST data**." message. And when I clicked any "edit" button, I received an Ajax error without any response Text:
[image]

Here are some buttons I found which don't work any more:

1. From Feed Import Setting (edit button doesn't work):
   [image]
2. From Content type Adding (add existing product button doesn't work):
   [image]

Does anyone have any idea why I got this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AJAX HTTP error occurred is very general error and it can be related to many things.

Based on your provided information we can say it's a core callback (`/system/ajax`) and the callback exists (Result code: 200).

The main problem is that it returns the empty response. This is most likely caused by [WSOD](https://www.drupal.org/node/158043) (white screen of death) which can be related to:

- out of memory issue ([increase `memory_limit`](https://www.drupal.org/node/207036) in your php.ini),
- timeout issue (increase `max_execution_time` in your php.ini),
- code issue (make sure you don't have any exit() or die() which terminates your code),
- cache issue (so please clear your cache, including memcached/redit if you're using it).

To debug this, you should:

1. Check your watchdog table for any errors (e.g. `drush ws --tail --full`).
2. Check your PHP error log for any PHP errors.
3. Use [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/) PHP extension, after [configuring](https://github.com/kenorb/kenorb/blob/master/conf/php/xdebug.ini) it enable `xdebug.auto_trace` parameter (only temporary), then reproduce the problem and check the trace file for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The link is very helpful. I just reboot my server and everything works fine